# How to calculate the difference in days in Pandas timeseries and visualize?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have financial data from January 2019 to July 2020. I would like to choose a date (lets say March 16, 2020) as date 0 and calculate number of days in +-30 day window and visualize it.

The x axis should have days from -30 to +30. Lastly draw horizontal line for the value at 0 days, like the one in the attached photo:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. To create a `Timestamp` from string you can use `pandas.Timestamp`
2. If you want to subtract or add from `Timestamp` several days use `pandas.DateOffset`
3. If you want plot something in Python, you can use `matplotlib.pyplot`. In you case `plot` function.
4. To change x ticks labels from timestamp to -30..30, use `pyplot.xticks`
5. To plot vertical line - `pyplot.vlines`

Simple example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0 = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-16')
x = pd.date_range(x0 - pd.DateOffset(30), x0 + pd.DateOffset(30), freq='D')

y = np.linspace(1, 10, len(x))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x[[0, 15, 30, 45, 60]], labels=[-30, -15, 0, 15, 30])
plt.show()
```